# outliers on multi-dimensional scaling plot?

Tags: r, outliers, multidimensional-scaling

I am in process of writing a grant where I am explaining my planned methylation analysis using R software "minfi". In the text of the grant I am mentioning looking for samples containing outliers in the multi-dimensional scaling (MDS) plot https://rdrr.io/bioc/minfi/man/mdsPlot.html . My question is how to more precisely define what is an outlier on a MDS plot? I know it is not logFC like on volcano plot, but is there is a way to quantify distance on MDA plot?

Comment: Can you provide a small example dataset?  Can you paste in a plot showing what you have in mind?  Note that some people w/ expertise in MDS don't use R.

Comment: I don't have my data yet, I am just writing a grant for the planned analysis. Here is example and sample data set used to create those MDS plots with minfi package: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/methylationArrayAnalysis/inst/doc/methylationArrayAnalysis.html#ref-Wu2010

Comment: Make up data.  Make a plot like what you have in mind.  I suspect this isn't answerable right now, & probably not by the people here w/ the most expertise in MDS, who don't use R.

Comment: I see, thank you for letting me know.